# How to find out which cipher suites are supported by the FTP client via SSL/TLS?

Tags: ssl, encryption, ftp, apache-mina

I am running an FTP server based on Apache MINA/FTP and I keep getting the following exception when trying to connect in SSL mode:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

I have verified that the cipher suites are set correctly on the client side like this:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory serverSocketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)
SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
String[] cipherSuites = serverSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();

SslConfigurationFactory sslConfigFactory = new SslConfigurationFactory();
sslConfigFactory.setKeystoreFile(keyStoreFile);
sslConfigFactory.setKeystorePassword(keyPass);
sslConfigFactory.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);
sslConfigFactory.setSslProtocol("SSL");
SslConfiguration sslConfig = sslConfigFactory.createSslConfiguration();
sslFactory.setSslConfiguration(sslConfig);
Listener listener = sslFactory.createListener();
serverFactory.addListener("SSL-listener", listener);
```

So, how do I verify that the cipher suites used on the client side match the ones that are provided on the server side?

I am using FileZilla and Cyberduck for testing, but I haven't found anything in the settings of these clients that would tell which cipher suites are supported.

Comment: Have you configured a keystore with a server certificate on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I found it useful to set the sysproperty `javax.net.debug="ssl"` at start time of the JVM and then watch stdout for a detailed report.